# discrepancy between Tensor flow model and Pyorch model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I trained a Unet model on the same dataset using both Tensor flow model and Pyorch. Both model showed a fine loss curve for training data, but the Pyorch validation data keeps zigzagging.

I think I'm good on Tensor flow but I'm new to Pyorch. Please, check if I made a mistake on Pyorch .

Below is the Tensor flow:

[image]

and this the Pyorch

[image]

The below code for Tensor flow :

```
class DataGen(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, ids, path, batch_size=8, image_size=128):
        self.ids = ids
        self.path = path
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.image_size = image_size
        self.on_epoch_end()
        
    def __load__(self, id_name):
        ## Path
        #image_path = os.path.join(self.path, id_name, "images", id_name) + ".png"
  #/content/drive/My Drive/mycolab/training/ patient0001 / patient0001
        image_path = os.path.join(self.path, id_name,  id_name,) + "_2CH_ED.mhd"
        
        #mask_path = os.path.join(self.path, id_name, "masks/")
        mask_path  = os.path.join(self.path, id_name,  id_name,) + "_2CH_ED_gt.mhd"
        
        # not required all_masks = os.listdir(mask_path)
        
        ## Reading Image
        #image = cv2.imread(image_path, 1)
        my_img1= io.imread(image_path , plugin='simpleitk')
        image=my_img1[0,:,:]
        #--------------image = cv2.merge((image,image,image))
        #image =convert_to_3_channel( cv2.resize(image, (self.image_size, self.image_size)))
        image = cv2.resize(image, (self.image_size, self.image_size))
        
        #image = cv2.merge((image,image,image,image))
        #image = cv2.merge((image,image,image,image))

        # same for mask
        my_mask1= io.imread(mask_path  , plugin='simpleitk')
        mask=my_mask1[0,:,:]
        mask= cv2.resize( mask, (self.image_size, self.image_size))
        #one_hot_tensor= K.one_hot(K.cast(  tf.convert_to_tensor(mask, dtype=tf.int32)     , 'int32'), num_classes=4)
        #mask=np.asarray(one_hot_tensor, np.float32)
        #mask=np.asarray(one_hot_tensor, np.int32)
        
        masks = [(mask == v) for v in range(4) ] #self.class_values]
        
        mask = np.stack(masks, axis=-1).astype('float')
        
        #masks = [(mask == v) for v in  range(4)]#self.class_values]
        #print("mask ttttttttttt5555555555:", type(masks))
        #mask = np.stack(masks, axis=-1).astype('float')
        # add background if mask is not binary
        #if mask.shape[-1] != 1:
        #    #print("adding background if mask is not binary******************++++++++__________________$$")
        #    background = 1 - mask.sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        #    mask = np.concatenate((mask, background), axis=-1)
        
        #mask = np.zeros((self.image_size, self.image_size, 1))
        
        ## Reading Masks
        #for name in all_masks:
        #    _mask_path = mask_path + name
        #    _mask_image = cv2.imread(_mask_path, -1)
        #    _mask_image = cv2.resize(_mask_image, (self.image_size, self.image_size)) #128x128
        #    _mask_image = np.expand_dims(_mask_image, axis=-1)
        #    mask = np.maximum(mask, _mask_image)
        #print("image &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&")  
        #print("image &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&")  
        #print("image &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&")
        #print(mask)  
        ## Normalizaing 
        #-------------image = image/255.0
        #----   check if tis correct mask = mask/255.0
        
        return image, mask# image.astype('float'), mask.astype('float')
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        #print("Index *************************************:", index )
        
        
        if(index+1)*self.batch_size > len(self.ids):
            self.batch_size = len(self.ids) - index*self.batch_size
            
        
        
       
        files_batch = self.ids[index*self.batch_size : (index+1)*self.batch_size]
        
        image = []
        mask  = []
        
        for id_name in files_batch:
            
            _img, _mask = self.__load__(id_name)
            image.append(_img ) #.astype('float'))
            mask.append(_mask ) #.astype('float'))
            
        image = np.array(image)
        mask  = np.array(mask)
        #print("image shape%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%",image.shape)
        #print("mask  shape%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%",mask.shape)

        return image , mask# image.astype('float'), mask.astype('float')
    
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        pass
    
    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.ids)/float(self.batch_size)))

# you may need to change variables names
image_size = 256
train_path ="path" #"dataset/stage1_train/"
epochs = 10 #70 # 5 # paper require 30
batch_size =1#32#1# 8
num_class = 4

print("train_ids  length:", len(train_ids))

## Validation Data Size
val_data_size = 10

valid_ids = train_ids[:val_data_size]

my_slice_index=2 # class index that we are calauting
## Training Ids
train_ids = next(os.walk(train_path))[1]

def down_block(x, filters, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", strides=1):
    
    c = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding=padding, strides=strides, activation="relu")(x)
    c = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding=padding, strides=strides, activation="relu")(c)
    
    p = keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2), (2, 2))(c)
    return c, p

def down_block_test(x, filters, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", strides=1):
    residual = x
    print("down_block: residual size", residual.shape)
    c = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding=padding, strides=strides, activation="relu")(x)
    print("down_block: c size", c.shape)
    c = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding=padding, strides=strides, activation="relu")(c)
    print("down_block: c2 size", c.shape)
    
    print("down_block: residual.shape[1]", residual.shape[1])
    print("down_block: residual.shape[3]", residual.shape[3])
    
    if residual.shape[3] != c.shape[3]:
            residual =  keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding=padding, strides=strides, activation="relu")(residual)
            
    c += residual
    p = keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2), (2, 2))(c)
    return c, p

def up_block(x, skip, filters, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", strides=1):
    us = keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    concat = keras.layers.Concatenate()([us, skip])
    c = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding=padding, strides=strides, activation="relu")(concat)
    c = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding=padding, strides=strides, activation="relu")(c)
    return c

def bottleneck(x, filters, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", strides=1):
    c = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding=padding, strides=strides, activation="relu")(x)
    c = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding=padding, strides=strides, activation="relu")(c)
    return c

#------------------------------------ model in the paper as Unet 1 ----------------------------------------
def UNet_test():
    f = [16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
    
    #inputs = keras.layers.Input((image_size, image_size, 3))
    inputs = keras.layers.Input((image_size, image_size, 1))
    
    p0 = inputs
    tf.print("********************************************p0: ")
    c1, p1 = down_block(p0, f[1]) #264 -> 128
    
    print("c1",c1.shape )
    print("p1",p1.shape )
    
    c2, p2 = down_block(p1, f[1]) #128 -> 64
    
    print("c2",c2.shape )
    print("p2",p2.shape )
    
    c3, p3 = down_block(p2, f[2]) #64 -> 32
    
    print("c3",c3.shape )
    print("p3",p3.shape ) 
    
    c4, p4 = down_block(p3, f[3]) #32->16
    
    print("c4",c4.shape )
    print("p4",p4.shape )
    
    c5, p5 = down_block(p4, f[3]) #16->8
    
    print("c5",c5.shape )
    print("p5",p5.shape )
    
    bn = bottleneck(p5, f[3]) # 8
    
    u1 = up_block(bn, c5, f[3]) #8 -> 16
    
    u2 = up_block(u1, c4, f[3]) #16 -> 32
    
    u3 = up_block(u2, c3, f[2]) #32 -> 64
    
    u4 = up_block(u3, c2, f[1]) #64 -> 128
    
    u5 = up_block(u4, c1, f[0]) #128 -> 256
    
    #outputs = keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (1, 1), padding="same", activation="sigmoid")(u4)
    outputs = keras.layers.Conv2D(num_class, (1, 1), padding="same", activation="softmax")(u5)
    #outputs = keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (1, 1), padding="same", activation="softmax")(u4)
    
    model = keras.models.Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model


model=UNet_test()

import segmentation_models as sm
#---------------------model =new_model(Resmodel,'sigmoid')#model_standard() # UNet_1()
#model.load_weights(weights_path)
#model.load_weights("ckpt") 
LR = 0.0001
optim = keras.optimizers.Adam(LR)

dice_loss_se2 = sm.losses.DiceLoss()
mae = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError( )
metrics = [ mae,sm.metrics.IOUScore(threshold=0.5), sm.metrics.FScore(threshold=0.5) , dice_loss_se2]

model.compile(optimizer=optim,loss= dice_loss_se2,metrics= metrics)

train_gen = DataGen(train_ids, train_path, image_size=image_size, batch_size=batch_size)
valid_gen = DataGen(valid_ids, train_path, image_size=image_size, batch_size=batch_size)

train_steps = len(train_ids)//batch_size
valid_steps = len(valid_ids)//batch_size

history =model.fit_generator(train_gen, validation_data=valid_gen, steps_per_epoch=train_steps, validation_steps=valid_steps, 
                    epochs=epochs)
```

and below code for pytorch:

```
class DoubleConv(nn.Module):
    """(convolution => [BN] => ReLU) * 2"""

    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, mid_channels=None):
        super().__init__()
        if not mid_channels:
            mid_channels = out_channels
        self.double_conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels, mid_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(mid_channels),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(mid_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.double_conv(x)


class Down(nn.Module):
    """Downscaling with maxpool then double conv"""

    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.maxpool_conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            DoubleConv(in_channels, out_channels)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.maxpool_conv(x)


class Up(nn.Module):
    """Upscaling then double conv"""

    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, bilinear=True):
        super().__init__()

        # if bilinear, use the normal convolutions to reduce the number of channels
        if bilinear:
            self.up = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear', align_corners=True)
            self.conv = DoubleConv(in_channels, out_channels, in_channels // 2)
        else:
            self.up = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, in_channels // 2, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
            self.conv = DoubleConv(in_channels, out_channels)

    def forward(self, x1, x2):
        x1 = self.up(x1)
        # input is CHW
        diffY = x2.size()[2] - x1.size()[2]
        diffX = x2.size()[3] - x1.size()[3]

        x1 = F.pad(x1, [diffX // 2, diffX - diffX // 2,
                        diffY // 2, diffY - diffY // 2])
        # if you have padding issues, see
        # https://github.com/HaiyongJiang/U-Net-Pytorch-Unstructured-Buggy/commit/0e854509c2cea854e247a9c615f175f76fbb2e3a
        # https://github.com/xiaopeng-liao/Pytorch-UNet/commit/8ebac70e633bac59fc22bb5195e513d5832fb3bd
        x = torch.cat([x2, x1], dim=1)
        return self.conv(x)


class OutConv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super(OutConv, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.conv(x)



class UNet_standard(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_channels, n_classes, bilinear=False):
        super(UNet_standard, self).__init__()
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.bilinear = bilinear

        self.inc = DoubleConv(n_channels, 64)
        self.down1 = Down(64, 128)
        self.down2 = Down(128, 256)
        self.down3 = Down(256, 512)
        factor = 2 if bilinear else 1
        self.down4 = Down(512, 1024 // factor)
        self.up1 = Up(1024, 512 // factor, bilinear)
        self.up2 = Up(512, 256 // factor, bilinear)
        self.up3 = Up(256, 128 // factor, bilinear)
        self.up4 = Up(128, 64, bilinear)
        self.outc = OutConv(64, n_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x1 = self.inc(x)
        x2 = self.down1(x1)
        x3 = self.down2(x2)
        x4 = self.down3(x3)
        x5 = self.down4(x4)
        x = self.up1(x5, x4)
        x = self.up2(x, x3)
        x = self.up3(x, x2)
        x = self.up4(x, x1)
        logits = self.outc(x)
        return logits
    


class DiceLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_classes):
        super(DiceLoss, self).__init__()
        self.n_classes = n_classes

    def _one_hot_encoder(self, input_tensor):
        tensor_list = []
        for i in range(self.n_classes):
            temp_prob = input_tensor == i  # * torch.ones_like(input_tensor)
            tensor_list.append(temp_prob.unsqueeze(1))
        output_tensor = torch.cat(tensor_list, dim=1)
        return output_tensor.float()

    def _dice_loss(self, score, target):
        target = target.float()
        smooth = 1e-5
        intersect = torch.sum(score * target)
        y_sum = torch.sum(target * target)
        z_sum = torch.sum(score * score)
        loss = (2 * intersect + smooth) / (z_sum + y_sum + smooth)
        loss = 1 - loss
        return loss

    def forward(self, inputs, target, weight=None, softmax=False):
        if softmax:
            inputs = torch.softmax(inputs, dim=1)
        target = self._one_hot_encoder(target)
        if weight is None:
            weight = [1] * self.n_classes
        assert inputs.size() == target.size(), 'predict {} & target {} shape do not match'.format(inputs.size(), target.size())
        class_wise_dice = []
        loss = 0.0
        for i in range(0, self.n_classes):
            dice = self._dice_loss(inputs[:, i], target[:, i])
            class_wise_dice.append(1.0 - dice.item())
            loss += dice * weight[i]
        return loss / self.n_classes

def iou_score(output, target):
    smooth = 1e-5

    if torch.is_tensor(output):
        output = torch.sigmoid(output).data.cpu().numpy()
    if torch.is_tensor(target):
        target = target.data.cpu().numpy()
    output_ = output > 0.5
    target_ = target > 0.5
    intersection = (output_ & target_).sum()
    union = (output_ | target_).sum()

    return (intersection + smooth) / (union + smooth)



class easy_Synapse_dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self,  split, transform=None):
        self.transform = transform  # using transform in torch!
        self.split = split
        
        if self.split == "train":
            use_path="path1"
        else:    
            #use_path="path1"
            use_path="path2"
        
        self.sample_list =next(os.walk(use_path))[1]  #open(os.path.join(list_dir, self.split+'.txt')).readlines()
        
        
        
        

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.sample_list)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        
        if self.split == "train":
            use_path="path1"
        else:    
            #use_path="path1"
            use_path="path2"
        '''
        if self.split == "train":
            slice_name = self.sample_list[idx].strip('\n')
            data_path = os.path.join(self.data_dir, slice_name+'.npz')
            data = np.load(data_path)
            image, label = data['image'], data['label']
        else:
            vol_name = self.sample_list[idx].strip('\n')
            filepath = self.data_dir + "/{}.npy.h5".format(vol_name)
            data = h5py.File(filepath)
            image, label = data['image'][:], data['label'][:]
        '''    
        #--------------------------------------------------------------------
        #
        image_path = os.path.join(use_path, self.sample_list[idx],  self.sample_list[idx],) + "_2CH_ED.mhd"
        #print(image_path)
        #mask_path = os.path.join(self.path, id_name, "masks/")
        mask_path  = os.path.join(use_path,  self.sample_list[idx],  self.sample_list[idx] ,) + "_2CH_ED_gt.mhd"
        #print(mask_path)
        # not required all_masks = os.listdir(mask_path)
        
        ## Reading Image
        #image = cv2.imread(image_path, 1)
        my_img1= iio.imread(image_path , plugin='simpleitk')
        image=my_img1[0,:,:]
        #--------------image = cv2.merge((image,image,image))
        #image =convert_to_3_channel( cv2.resize(image, (self.image_size, self.image_size)))
        image = cv2.resize(image, (img_size, img_size))
        
        #image = cv2.merge((image,image,image))
        #image  = np.moveaxis(image , 2, 0)
        
        #image = cv2.merge((image,image,image,image))

        # same for mask
        my_mask1= iio.imread(mask_path  , plugin='simpleitk')
        mask=my_mask1[0,:,:]
        mask= cv2.resize( mask, (img_size, img_size))
        #one_hot_tensor= K.one_hot(K.cast(  tf.convert_to_tensor(mask, dtype=tf.int32)     , 'int32'), num_classes=4)
        #mask=np.asarray(one_hot_tensor, np.float32)
        #mask=np.asarray(one_hot_tensor, np.int32)
        
        #masks = [(mask == v) for v in range(4) ] #self.class_values]
        
        #mask = np.stack(masks, axis=-1).astype('float')
        '''
        mask = torch.Tensor(mask)
        mask=torch.nn.functional.one_hot(mask.to(torch.int64) , num_classes=4)
        mask = mask.to(torch.float)
        mask = mask.permute(2, 0, 1)
        '''
        label=mask
        
        #--------------------------------------------------------------------
        #print("image ", image.shape) 
        #print("mask ", mask.shape)
        
        '''
        transform = transforms.Compose([
                transforms.ToTensor()
        ])
        '''
        
        image = torch.from_numpy(image.astype(np.float32)).unsqueeze(0)
        label = torch.from_numpy(label.astype(np.float32))
        
        
        #if self.split != "train":
        #   image = torch.from_numpy(image.astype(np.float32)).unsqueeze(0)
        #   label = torch.from_numpy(label.astype(np.float32))
        
        
        sample = {'image': image, 'label': label}
        
        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)
            
        
        #print("sample[image].size() ", sample["image"].shape) 
        #print("sample[label].size() ", sample["label"].shape) 
       
        return sample# sample#transform(image), transform(mask).squeeze(0)  #sample
        
#logging.basicConfig(level=logging.NOTSET)
img_size=256# 224
torch.manual_seed(42)
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print(device)

#------------------------

db_train = easy_Synapse_dataset( split="train",
                               transform=None) #transforms.Compose(
                                  #[RandomGenerator(output_size=[img_size, img_size])]))
print("The length of train set is: {}".format(len(db_train)))

   

train_loader = DataLoader(db_train, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)#, num_workers=8, pin_memory=True,
                             #worker_init_fn=worker_init_fn)
    

db_test = easy_Synapse_dataset( split="test_vol")    
val_loader = DataLoader(db_test, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, num_workers=1)    


#---------------------

# Now we can create a model and send it at once to the device
#----model = ManualLinearRegression().to(device)
'''
vit_patches_size=16
config_vit = CONFIGS['R50-ViT-B_16']
config_vit.n_classes = 4#args.num_classes
config_vit.n_skip =3  # args.n_skip
if 'R50-ViT-B_16'.find('R50') != -1:
        config_vit.patches.grid = (int(img_size / vit_patches_size), int(img_size / vit_patches_size))

'''
#----------------------




model =UNet_standard( 1, 4).to(device)





# We can also inspect its parameters using its state_dict
#print(model.state_dict())

lr =0.01# 1e-1
n_epochs = 10

loss_fn =DiceLoss(4)#num_classes) nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean')
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=lr)#optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0001)



#-------------------------------------------
def make_train_step(model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    # Builds function that performs a step in the train loop
    def train_step(x, y):
        # Sets model to TRAIN mode
        model.train()
        # Makes predictions
        yhat = model(x)
        #d0, d1, d2,  d3= model(x)
        #print(yhat.shape)
        # Computes loss
        #loss =muti_bce_loss_fusion2(d0, d1,d2,  d3, y)# loss_fn(yhat, y, softmax=True) #loss_fn(y, yhat)
        loss = loss_fn(yhat, y, softmax=True)
        # Computes gradients
        loss.backward()
        # Updates parameters and zeroes gradients
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        # Returns the loss
        return loss.item()
    
    # Returns the function that will be called inside the train loop
    return train_step

# Creates the train_step function for our model, loss function and optimizer
train_step = make_train_step(model, loss_fn, optimizer)

y_val_average_loss = []
y_average_loss = []
x_epoch= []
# For each epoch...
for epoch in tqdm(range(n_epochs)):
    
    losses = []
    val_losses = []
    iou_metric = []
    #for x_batch, y_batch in train_loader:
    for i_batch, sampled_batch in enumerate(train_loader):
        x_batch, y_batch = sampled_batch['image'], sampled_batch['label']
        #x_batch, y_batch =image_batch.cpu(), label_batch.cpu()
        # the dataset "lives" in the CPU, so do our mini-batches
        # therefore, we need to send those mini-batches to the
        # device where the model "lives"
        x_batch = x_batch.to(device)
        y_batch = y_batch.to(device)
        #print( x_batch.shape , "  ",y_batch.shape )
        loss = train_step(x_batch, y_batch)
        #print("loss = ",loss )
        losses.append(loss)
    
    #print('loss : %f' % (sum(losses) / len(losses) ))
    
    avg=sum(losses) / len(losses)
    y_average_loss .append (avg)
    print('loss : %f' % (avg) )
    
    losses = [] #clear
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        #for x_val, y_val in val_loader:
        for i_batch, sampled_batch2 in enumerate(val_loader):
            x_val, y_val = sampled_batch2['image'], sampled_batch2['label']
            
            x_val = x_val.to(device)
            y_val = y_val.to(device)
            
            model.eval()

            d3 = model(x_val)
            #d0, d1, d2,  d3  = model(x_val)
            val_loss =loss_fn(d3, y_val, softmax=True) # loss_fn(y_val, yhat)
            iou = iou_score(d3, y_val)
            
            val_losses.append(val_loss.item())
            iou_metric.append(iou.item())
        #print('Validation loss : %f' % (sum(val_losses) / len(val_losses) ))
        print('Validation iou : %f' % (sum(iou_metric) / len(iou_metric) ))
        
        val_avg=sum(val_losses) / len(val_losses)
        y_val_average_loss .append (val_avg)
        x_epoch.append (epoch)
        print('Validation loss : %f' % (  val_avg  ))
        
        val_losses = [] # clear
        iou_metric = []
# Checks model's parameters
#print(model.state_dict())
```

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: I was expecting the tensorflow and pytorch will get the same result, But pytorch is different.

Comment: You may have diferences as it is hard to train with the exact conditions of same weight-initialization, same data-split, same data normalization etc.

Comment: But I tried it many times. Tensorflow works fine while pytorch validation is not decreasing like Tensorflow validation.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by using different Unet implementation from https://github.com/usuyama/pytorch-unet/blob/master/pytorch_unet.py

[image]